# Comparing two types of delayed computation

Tags: recursion, lambda, scheme, racket

I have an assignment in which i need to explain the impact on the memory using two types of delayed computation. The code solves the hanoi problem.

Type 1:

```
(define count-4 (lambda (n) (count-4-helper n (lambda (x) x)))
(define count-4-helper (lambda (n cont)
 (if (= n 1)
 (cont 1)
 (count-4-helper (- n 1) (lambda(res) (cont (+ 1 (* 2 res))))))))
```

Type 2:

```
(define count-5 (lambda (n) (count-5-helper n (lambda () 1)))
(define count-5-helper (lambda (n cont)
 (if (= n 1)
 (cont)
 (count-5-helper (- n 1) (lambda() (+ 1 (* 2 (cont))))))))
```

The first case is the classic syntax of delayed computation. The second case is the same only it doesn't get any arguments and just returns the initial value.
The question is which one of those function is tail-recursive?(i think both them are). And how different is their memory consumption? The second should be more effective but i can't really explain.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in these two lambdas:

```
(lambda (res) (cont (+ 1 (* 2 res))))

(lambda () (+ 1 (* 2 (cont))))
```

In one of them but not the other, `cont` is called in tail position with respect to the lambda.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't pay attention to the order.